# How to solve for $x$ in $(16)^\frac{1}{x} = \frac{10}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to solve this equation: $$(16)^\frac{1}{x} = \frac{10}{3}$$

By the way this is coming from another equation so I've already solve half of it.

Comment: What have you tried? Include it in your question body - editing is perfectly possible.

Comment: Hint: use logariths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$16^{1/x}=\frac{10}3\implies \frac1x\log16=\log\frac{10}3\implies x=\cdots$$

Comment: $x=\frac{\log 16}{\log \frac{10}{3}}$ ?

Comment: Precisely. Now all you have to do is simplify.

Comment: How? Isn't it already simplified?

Comment: Note that $\log16=4\log2$ and $\log\frac{10}3=\log2-\log3+\log5$

Comment: $x=\frac{4\log2}{\log10-\log3}$ ?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

$16^{1/x} = 10/3\implies {1\over x}\ln16=\ln 10 -\ln3 $.  This follows from the rules for logarithms.  Next,${1\over x}\ln16=\ln 10 -\ln3 \implies {1\over x} = {\ln 10-\ln3\over\ln16}$.  Therefore, $x= {\ln 16\over\ln 10-\ln3}$.  To clean this up, just use the rules for logs.